# kubernetes resources jump between namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

I have a Kubernetes cluster which has 5 different services.
After cluster deployment I can run:

```
kubectl get pods
```

and see all my pods. But after a few minutes when I run the same command again, I see:

```
No resources found.
```

And I'm able to see my pods only after running:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

Can someone explain what is my problem?

Comment: on which namespace do your containers run? make sure that your current config is set to this namespace

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Kuberenetes adds namespace: dev to my ~/.kube/config. If I delete it, all works, but then Kuberenetes put it there once again after some time. Can't understand when and why

Comment: what's your kubernetes distribution? maybe your setup has a weird controller that does that. also are your pods crashing or they stay in ready state? Maybe `--all-namespaces` shows stopped pods as well.

Comment: My kubernetes is 1.10.11. My pods staying in the 'Running' state.

Comment: @alexarsh, could you share your deployments, services and kube config?
Also `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide` would be appreciated.